# Solr Index Using SQL Stored Procedure - Variables and CTE's allowed?

Tags: sql-server, solr, lucene, common-table-expression

I am using Solr to index results from a "semi-complicated" stored procedure in SQL Server (2005).

By semi-complicated I mean that I declare some variables inside the SP and create a Calendar CTE (recursively, I know, I know) to fill in dates from another table where my data is stored.  I dump the results into a temp table and select from there to get my query results.

I've read that if you are not doing a simple select within an SP being indexed by solr, you must include SET NOCOUNT ON; in order to get the correct results, which I have done.

For some reason, my data is not being indexed after full data import.  If I do not declare any of the variables and comment out the CTE portion, the index works as expected.  Does anyone know if it is LEGAL in an SP indexed by solr to declare variables and make use of a recursive CTE or any CTE at all?

I can post code if necessary, but I am more looking for a general answer to the above question.

I welcome any feedback on any other possible solutions as well that may not require a Calendar CTE, besides the obvious "create a Calendar table".

**EDIT/UPDATE:** 
I've narrowed the issue down to the JOIN on the temp table populated by the CTE.  I am joining on other temp tables that aren't populated by JOIN on CTE and they can be imported and indexed correctly.  Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: i'd drop the stored-procedure tag and add the generic sql-server tag to get more visibility to this. Just my two cents